# Increase Audio Volume of MOV-Video in OS X

Tags: macos, audio, video, encoding, sound-volume

I have a MOV-Video file and I want to increase the volume of the audio layer without reencoding the entire video.

Is there a way to solve this problem?

Comment: I'm not sure if this is the right SE to ask this question. Maybe http://avp.stackexchange.com is a better place? In the meantime have a look at [ffmpeg](http://ffmpeg.org). [Here](http://ffmpeg.org/pipermail/ffmpeg-user/2012-February/004696.html) it is explained how you can add audio to video without re-encoding. You can extract the original audio, increase the gain and then add it back to the video with the linked method.

Comment: Your answer already completely solved my problem! :)

Answer (score 4):

One thing you can do is use a video viewer like [IINA](https://lhc70000.github.io/iina/) on macOS, which allows you to go beyond the 100% volume limit. It allows you to set the volume up to 1000%, so if you are trying to view an unusually quiet video, you can increase the volume in IINA without having to crank up your computer's volume too much.

In IINA: You can set maximum volume (100-1000%) in Preference, and use ↑ to set volume larger than 100%.

Comment: Only after setting value more than 100 in application Preferences, you can increase the volume to more than 100